# Is there a way I can overlay the dot plot over my bar plot according to the bar for each point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add the points associated with each bar to the ggplot2 graph. I don't understand why the points are not organized like the graphs. How can I arrange the points according to the bars and not the x axis vars?

I tried making another overlay but it did not split the data in the desired way:

[image: Graph of ggplot2]

```
ggplot(rdata, aes(variable, value, fill = Treatment)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold")) +
  scale_fill_grey(name = "") +
  ylab("Relative CD11b Expression") +
  xlab("") +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se, position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 0.3, width = 0.3) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_identity())
```

Below are the sample data values

```
   Treatment    variable     value
1    HFD+LPS    Amygdala 1.7184535
2    HFD+LPS    Amygdala 1.9904329
3    HFD+LPS    Amygdala 1.6025593
4    HFD+LPS    Amygdala 2.2624420
5    HFD+LPS    Amygdala 2.1697814
6    HFD+LPS    Amygdala 1.3641929
7    CHD+LPS    Amygdala 0.8125338
8    CHD+LPS    Amygdala 1.0721207
9    CHD+LPS    Amygdala 2.7181632
10   CHD+LPS    Amygdala 1.1883906
11   CHD+LPS    Amygdala 1.7618055
12   CHD+LPS    Amygdala 1.4261327
13       HFD    Amygdala 1.3379231
14       HFD    Amygdala 0.8181424
15       HFD    Amygdala 0.7176474
16       HFD    Amygdala 0.8470046
17       HFD    Amygdala 1.2694769
18       HFD    Amygdala 2.0215795
19      CHD     Amygdala 1.9141461
20      CHD     Amygdala 2.1411518
21      CHD     Amygdala 2.1104577
22      CHD     Amygdala 0.9601264
23      CHD     Amygdala 2.3873088
24      CHD     Amygdala 2.5354091
25   HFD+LPS Hippocampus 1.8772147
26   HFD+LPS Hippocampus 0.7938240
27   HFD+LPS Hippocampus 1.9498375
28   HFD+LPS Hippocampus 1.7736435
29   HFD+LPS Hippocampus 3.4728941
30   HFD+LPS Hippocampus 1.3806457
31   CHD+LPS Hippocampus 0.6630722
32   CHD+LPS Hippocampus 0.6639194
33   CHD+LPS Hippocampus 0.7283285
34   CHD+LPS Hippocampus 1.9721344
35   CHD+LPS Hippocampus 3.7725719
36   CHD+LPS Hippocampus 1.3293153
37       HFD Hippocampus 0.5718558
38       HFD Hippocampus 0.5955154
39       HFD Hippocampus 0.4096584
40       HFD Hippocampus 0.8230605
41       HFD Hippocampus 1.1175684
42       HFD Hippocampus 0.8778159
43      CHD  Hippocampus 0.3466085
44      CHD  Hippocampus 0.3950703
45      CHD  Hippocampus 0.5400010
46      CHD  Hippocampus 0.2032497
47      CHD  Hippocampus 0.8487227
48      CHD  Hippocampus 0.9546050
```

I expect each point to be at the bar associated with it for example if a point is for Amygdala and CHD, it should only be in the bar associated with that

Comment: Could you add some example data, the entirety of the plotting code and/or an image of the current plotting result? It's hard to help if we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: I added the graph and the corresponding sample data

Comment: Does changing the position specification for `geom_jitter()` to `position = position_dodge(0.9)` (similar to the other geom layers) help?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you!!